# Can't get Heads to show with only one record

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am pulling down some records that have a COUNT of 0 or more than 1. The query works and pulls down properly and looks great in the SQL Results. But I am looping through the results and creating a Header and grouping them based on Country and listing the name of the users for that Country.

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT u.ContactName
      ,cu.[User ID]
      ,c.Name
      ,c.ID
      ,cu.[Foreign Table]
      ,count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.ID) AS user_in_this_country
FROM   dbo.Country AS c
INNER JOIN   dbo.CountryUser AS cu ON c.ID = cu.[Foreign ID]
INNER JOIN   dbo.UserColder  AS  u ON cu.[User ID] = u.ID
WHERE  EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   CountryUser AS cu2
    WHERE  cu2.[Foreign ID] = cu.[Foreign ID]
    AND    cu2.[User ID] <> cu.[User ID]
    AND    cu2.[Foreign Table] = 'Country')
    )
    t
    WHERE user_in_this_country > 1 or user_in_this_country = 0
    ORDER BY Name ASC
```

This would pull down data that would look like:

```
Justin United States 2
Bob United States 2
```

Then my method to loop through and add the headers/group is:

```
string lastValue = "";
protected string AddGroupingHeader(string Value)
{


    //Get the data field value of interest for this row 
    string currentValue = Value;


    //Specify name to display if dataFieldValue is a database NULL 
    if (currentValue.Length == 0)
    {
        currentValue = "";
    }


    //See if there's been a change in value 
    if (lastValue != currentValue)
    {
        //There's been a change! Record the change and emit the header 
        lastValue = currentValue;
        return "<div style='float: left; font-size: 16px; margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;'>" + currentValue + "</div>";
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

and in the aspx I am just passing the value like so:

```
<%# AddGroupingHeader(Eval("Name").ToString())%>
```

Now if I have several records it works propery and displays like:

```
United States
 - Justin
 - Bob

China
 - Frank
 - Ted
```

But and this is the problem. If I just have:

```
United States Justin
United Bob
```

Then it doesn't put the header. It does this:

```
Justin
Bob
```

Sorry for the long post, but does anyone see anything that would cause this, I've been stumped for 2 days. :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `float` style. The method `AddGroupingHeader` can be simplified. You would call it passing only the value, which serves as header.

```
string _lastHeader;

protected string AddGroupingHeader(string header)
{ 
    if (header != _lastHeader) {
        _lastHeader = header;
        return "<div style='font-size: 16px; margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;'>" + header + "</div>";
    } 
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, gave that a try but header still doesnt show with only one country being returned.

Comment: Have you tried right click (context menu) on your page in the browser and "View Source"? Here you can inspect the resulting HTML code. May be the header is there but not displayed for some reason. Another thing you can try is to always return a header. Either the one returned by the query or a constant text. It might give you a clue, whether the problem is in the logic, the query or the display.